# npm start - developing React app - any way to set 'base href' or forward traffic to my back-end?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am modifying existing React application which uses the relative URLs e.g.: `/server/fetchRouteInfo`.
The react app runs in context of a hostname e.g.: `local.website.com`, so it all works nicely as URLs get resolved to: `local.website.com/server/...`

I've found the `npm start` convenient to use to develop this React application. The problem is because of npm, my front-end app gets hosted under: `localhost:3000`, so the relative URLs no longer resolve to correct back-end and external resources.

What's the best way to connect my front-end app to desired back-end?

I've tried to use HTML `<base href="local.website.com">` but it breaks the `npm` internal calls e.g. to `static.js`.

I know that I could modify the relative URLs to full absolute, but that's not the way I want to go.

Perhaps there is a way to forward / proxy-pass any traffic that goes to npm to my endpoint? In other words if there is request like: `localhost:3000/server/...` it would get internally proxied to: `local.website.com/server/...`.

What's the common way to solve my problem, namely how to connect front-end to external back-end given the front-end uses relative URLs.

Comment: Where you have defined the base href?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the proxy in `package.json`. Just add one more parameter `proxy` with the desired value.

For more information, please refer to [Proxying in Development](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)

Comment: Cool, now I can fetch JSON or images from the back-end. The problem that I still need to solve is that I need to login myself to the back-end. There is standalone: `/login` HTML page with login forms, however when I visit: `localhost:3000/login` I see my React front-end instead of forwarded HTML from the back-end.
Interestingly when I don't include the `Accept` header (e.g. using CURL) on the request the `npm` decides to actually forward my request to the back-end and I retrieve HTML correctly. Question how can I do that in the browser?

Comment: The scenario where you don't include `Accept` header seems surprising to me. For the other scenario, as you are running on the localhost, it always fetches the base HTML file and thus loads our React data. Based on that, it looks for `/login` in our react application and route accordingly.

Comment: This behavior with `Accept` header is described here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Answer (score 0):

On React page there is proxy section: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/#configuring-the-proxy-manually

Looking up the component Github: https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware

There is a way to provide custom filter.

Instructions:

- Install component: `npm install --save-dev http-proxy-middleware`
- Create file: `src/setupProxy.js` with this config

  ```
  const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
  module.exports = function(app) {

      var filter = function(pathname) {
          if (pathname.match('^/static')) {
              return false;
          }

          return !pathname.match('^/$');
      };

      app.use(
          proxy(filter,{
              target: 'https://local.backend',
              changeOrigin: true
          })
      );
  };
  ```
- npm start

This will redirect all traffic, except the: `/` (this is where my React app is served) and starting with `/static` (some NPM JavaScript).

I am not sure if it's the easiest way or not. I would've been easier if there is dedicated namespace e.g.: `/api` that you could use.

There was a caveat though. If you first need to login to your back-end which sets session cookies, those cookies won't persist if you use: `localhost:3000` path (the localhost is not valid domain for cookies to be set). 
My workaround was to add the entry in: `/etc/hosts` and create bogus domain.
`127.0.0.1 local.host` then use: `local.host:3000` endpoint.

Another issue you might encounter if the session cookie is: `Secure`, that means that it won't be set for unencrypted protocols. Simply start the npm with `https` support: `HTTPS=true npm start` and contact using: `https://local.host:3000` endpoint.